# Shell - read files to bytes and encode to base64

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to shell script and I ofter use a simple `cat` to read a file. Now I need to read file as bytes and encode it into base64.

Is there any option to execute it on shell? About encode to base64 is simple but I'm not sure how to read file as bytes.

I have a json file that I need to read and post it to another API. The request body is something like:

```
{ "report_file_content": "b' P...." }
```

Our backend in .Net parse it to another object - they are expecting a byte array encoded in Base64.

I would like to read the file as array of bytes, encode it to base64 and set to variable. I'm just confused how to read as array of bytes.

Comment: Unless you're implementing base64 yourself, you don't need an array of bytes. Just call `base64 filename`, or pipe into it `cat file | base64`

Comment: I think backend is parsing base64 to byte array then parse to original file.

Comment: Keep in mind that newlines matter: `printf '%s\n' 'hello world' | base64` and `printf '%s' 'hello world' | base64` (with no newline) give different results

Comment: Is there any way to create an array of bytes from a file?

Comment: Pretty sure shell just works with characters, not bytes: `shrug='¯\_(ツ)_/¯'` then `echo "${shrug:4:1}"` prints `ツ`.

Comment: So, show some code or describe in more detail about what exactly you're trying to accomplish

Comment: @glennjackman check if the edit helps, please

Comment: Note with the shrug unicode string, `printf '%s' "$shrug" | base64` outputs `wq9cXyjjg4QpXy/Crw==` which looks like the right length. So I wonder if you need to do anything special.

Comment: I'd do `encoded=$(printf '%s' "$(< filename)" | base64)` which will strip the trailing newline off the file's data.

Comment: Your insisting on a data type array of bytes does not match shell programming. There are normally lots of existing commands/programs for various purposes you can simply call from your script. `base64` can do base64 encoding or decoding. You don't need to care about if the data is processed internally as bytes or whatever. You simply pass the input as a file or as `stdin` and get the output as `stdout` which you can redirect to a file if needed. I suggest to show an example of input file and the corresponding expected output. Show an example how you want to use the data in your script.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer was given in comment.

`cat filename | base64`

No special conversion to byte array is needed, since byte array is just a representation of a blob data of binary file, which coincides with file content